# Ubuntu 22.04: External monitors are not visible on DP over USB3.2C

Tags: drivers, 22.04, multiple-monitors, asus, dock

I'm struggling to connect my external monitors to my new computer via my dock. I have been using this dock for 2-years with my work computer and it works without an issue. So, I am sure that there is no issue on dock and monitors. And, the built-in HDMI is also working on the new computer.

USB's inputs (i.e. mouse and keyboard) work with the dock, but monitors don't.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Computer | ASUS Vivobook 17X K3704V |
| OS | Ubuntu 22.04 |
| Kernel version | 6.2.0-26-generic |
| Dock Model | ISY IDO 1000 (https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_isy-ido-1000-usb-adapter-silber-2737586.html) |

`lsusb -t`:

```bash
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 13, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 15, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 17, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl88XXau, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
```

`lspci`:

```bash
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a706
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a7a0 (rev 04)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a71d
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device a74f
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a77d (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Device a77f
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
0000:00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51be (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 519d (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a74d
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1aa (rev 03)
```

`xrandr -q`:

```bash
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  40.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I checked many issue pages on askubuntu, stackoverflow but I couldn't find any solution for it. I am looking forward to hearing from solution from you!

Thanks in advance.